# Making CSS position attribute dependent on window size and platform

Tags: css

I have a footer that runs across the bottom of my web page. If the user is viewing the page on a desktop, the footer needs to have `position:fixed;` to the bottom of the screen. However, according to my UX spec, when viewed on a phone or other small screen (width less than 768px), the footer needs to be *either*

- fixed to the bottom of the screen if the content is shorter than the height of the screen, *or*
- absolute positioned to the bottom of the *page* (i.e., the content) if the content is longer (taller) than the screen, and therefore invisible until scrolled. This is to save precious screen real-estate.

Can this be done within CSS? If so, how?
Or do I need to rely on Javascript? Let's assume that the page is currently not using any Javascript yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you need your footer to always be fixed if the user is viewing the website on a screen wider than 768px;

This can be achieved using media queries that detect the screen width and apply fixed position to the footer like this:

```
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

To solve the mobile issue you need to apply what we call a **sticky footer**. This can be done easily using something like `flexbox`

consider the following markup:

```
<body class="Site">
  <header>…</header>
  <main class="Site-content">…</main>
  <footer>…</footer>
</body>
```

The CSS will be (you might need to prefix the properties)

```
@media(max-width: 768px) {
  .Site {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .Site-content {
    flex: 1 auto 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple with css (if you are only detecting the device by width).

First start off with a sticky footer template (note the top row is optional here):

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="table">
        <div class="top row"><div class="cell">header</div></div>
        <div class="middle row"><div class="container cell">body</div></div>
        <div class="bottom row"><div class="cell">footer</div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, 
body {min-height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;}

#wrapper {position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;}

.table {display:table; width:100%; height:100%;}
.row {display:table-row;}
.cell {display:table-cell;}
```

This will meet your requirements of the footer always being at the bottom of the page or pushed off if the content is too large.  I have used the `display:table` option as it is compatible back to ie8 but there are many other ways to get a sticky footer

Now add a media query to fix the footer for larger widths:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .bottom {
        position:fixed; 
        bottom:0; 
        left:0; 
        right:0;
    }
}
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ra0hekx4/2)